# BHO installation and not loading with IE, not connecting to desktop through socket

Tags: internet-explorer, sockets, 32-bit, bho, gecko

We have a small C# application that have unified login system implemented. BHO in internet explorer picks the url to see if the url is registered otherwise asks User to register their credentials with desktop application. Firefox component and IE Bho object communicates via socket server.

The challenge is in IE bho is not loading automatically and only loads if run in administrator mode, and even if it loads it does not connect to desktop server. I am unable to find reason on why bho and firefox component wouldnt connect to desktop application.

There are loads of information like 64 bit vs 32 bit compilation model for IE BHO object. This application essentially connects on same PC and is secure in that sense that it doesnt communicate with outside world in anyway.

So to summarize.

1. IE BHO should load in any configuration in Protected mode (32 bit, 64 bit).
2. Components should be able to connect to socket server running on same desktop.
3. regsvr32 registers IE BHO successfully which is a VC++ BHO object

thanks,

HELP will be HIGHLY appreciated as I have been on this problem for quite sometime.

Comment: Does your BHO appear in IE's addon list in Tools > Manage Addons? Does it act differently if you disable Protected Mode and Enhanced Protected Mode, or run in different versions of Internet Explorer? Does the correct BHO registry key exist in both `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{ YOUR GUID }` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects\{ YOUR GUID }`? Is that class correctly registered for COM beneath CLSID? What protocol are you using to connect to your other app?